# Bootstrap strange text flickering during hover animation

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I found a strange problem. During animation, dark colors are flickering.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/madklm/pen/ExNMzaQ)

Partially `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` fixes the problem, but it makes font tighter and brighter.
Problem occurs on chrome and edge. Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code to your span elements.

```html
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
```

This should cover all browsers as far as I've tested.

Comment: It works, but it also change text style https://i.imgur.com/gfD1hnP.png
looks thinner

Comment: Have you tried giving it a default font-style or font-weight?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help